# jQuery $.post not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm using $.post to send a form via ajax to a PHP page, which returns JSON data. Once upon a time, it worked perfectly, and the function(data) executed as normal. Somehow, I've broke it, and now it doesn't even touch the function(data). I've tried undoing most of what I've done, but I still can't find the problem.

Here's the script :

```
$("#modifyhome").submit(function(event) {
    if($("#modifyhome").valid()) {  
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $( this ),
            title = $form.find('input[name="title"]').val(),
            content = $form.find('textarea[name="content"]').val();

        $.post("?action=page-accueil", {"title": title, "content": content},
            function(data) {            
                if(data['error'] == 1)
                {           
                    $().message(data['message']);
                    $("div.jquery-message").effect("shake", {times: 3}, 900);
                }
                else if(data['error'] == 0)
                {           
                    $().message(data['message']);
                    $("div.jquery-message").effect("bounce", {times: 3}, 900);
                }
                else
                {           
                    $().message("Erreur de connexion au serveur : veuillez r&eacute;essayer.");
                    $("div.jquery-message").effect("shake", {times: 3}, 900);
                }
            }, "json"
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $("[id^=qtip-]").effect("pulsate", {times: 3}, 600);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And here is what the PHP page (?action=page-accueil) returns :

```
{"error":0,"message":"Page modifi&eacute;e."}
```

That all checks out as valid JSON, but it's as if jQuery doesn't recognize it for some reason. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Add an error callback and post the results. `$.post(...).fail(function(){ console.log(arguments); });`

Comment: You'll get useful information if you change your `post` call to an equivalent `ajax` call and use the `error` callback.

Comment: Did you check you error/network console using chrome or firebug for firefox?

Comment: @R.S: Yes I did, 0 errors.
T.J. Crowder: Working on it now.

Comment: There is a conflict in your description. I see you post to `?action=page-accueil` but your PHP page `?page=page-accueil` returns.
The different is "action=" vs "page=". It maybe the case your php didn't return anything.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `$.post` to return JSON, instead of just using `$.getJSON`

Comment: Wait a second, why are you passing GET data through the query string with a POST request? Your data needs to be all GET or all POST. (Update: even if it is technically possible, it's bad practice.)

Comment: @Blazemonger I don't think that's true... you can send both get and post vars in the same request in this way. At least, it works in my server-side environment.

Comment: Blazemonger: Because I'm posting data to the PHP page, the return data can change, I just gave that as an example.
Derek: Indeed, I meant "action=". Changed it now.
T.J. Crowder: Changed it to an ajax call, error returns : "parsererror", even though the JSON is valid...

Comment: @Cuonic parseerror means your json is not valid. Look for extra characters before or after the ajax request. Try logging the first argument's responseText parameter.

Comment: responseText : "{"error":0,"message":"Page modifi&eacute;e."}"

No space, nothing, not seeing what's wrong. :|

Comment: @KevinB : Got any solutions ?

Comment: That's valid json, i don't know why you're getting parseerror, unless the outer `"` is part of the json, though i assume you just added that to show that it's a string

Comment: @KevinB Yeah it was copied from Firebug's DOM tab. I seriously have no idea as to why it doesn't work, it's holding up development :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear about what the problem is. At the beginning you say

> Somehow, I've broke it, and now it doesn't even touch the function(data)

but then you say that jQuery is not recognizing your JSON, which means the callback function was invoked. You need to test each phase of the process to discover your error. Browser console is a must for debugging in this case.

Test cases:

1. is the server returning anything? If not

   - Is there an error in the php code? May return 500 error or could return OK, but with error message as string.
   - Is there a same-origin issue? Perhaps going form HTTP -> HTTPS?
2. If the server is returning something but it is not being parsed correctly.

   - Is the data being returned valid JSON? For PHP you should use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function if available or something similar. jQuery side there is jQuery.parseJSON()
   - Is there an issue with response-type headers? In this case you will want to use normal $.ajax and set the beforeSend parameter to something like beforeSend: function(xhr){ xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript") }. You will need to further research this option.

To test any of this it is fundamental that you are familiar with the browser console. [Chrome Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)  or [Firebug Net Tab](http://getfirebug.com/network)

Comment: Check out the comments in the original post, I'm quite familiar with Firebug, the PHP file (which is on the exact same domain, no HTTPS) is returning the following : {"error":0,"message":"Page modifi&eacute;e."} which is valid JSON, according to jsonlint.com, but the $.ajax function is returning "parsererror".

Comment: try setting the dataType response to "text" rather than "json", and then use jQuery.parseJSON(data).

Answer (score -1):

I used to get this problem too, I am exactly not sure of the reason why. But I have a solution that works.

```
$.post("?action=page-accueil", 
    {"title": title, "content": content},
    function(data) {
        data = eval("("+data+")");
        //.... Then continue it
});
```

Or, use `.parseJSON()` function to read the string as JSON, if you dont want to use `eval()`

```
$.post("?action=page-accueil", 
    {"title": title, "content": content},
    function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        //.... Then continue it
});
```

Comment: Using ````eval```` (when not necessary) seems to be a terrible idea in terms of coding style and performance, at least to me.

Comment: This only happens when you forget to set the `dataType` to `"json"` when returning json, which was correctly done in this case.

Comment: @KevinB, Not always I remember having exactly same problem, even providing 'json' as a return type.

Comment: @dirkk, Why exactly would that be a problem here? I understand the risks associated with using `eval()` and none of them apply here.

Comment: If you set the datatype to json and get a string instead of an object or array, you've encountered a major bug (or your json wasn't json)

Comment: No, the output received was also JSON, but somehow not accessible an JSON object, so I found that `eval()` way which helped.

Comment: Right, but there's no such thing as a JSON object, it's either an object or a json string. If you specify a json datatype and get a string, something's wrong.

Comment: @Starx First of all that you are doing a function call, which is not necessary. You are doing this simply to circumvent some bug in your or some 3rd party code. Of course, one sometimes has to do such stuff to work with crappy code provided by others. But as I would guess that the server response is also under your control, why bother by using this hack? (Of course, if the server output is not under your control, things might be different)

Comment: @KevinB, I meant JSON as an object and I think you understood that.